# ViewModel not recognized in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My viewmodel in different project(class library). I added reference. But when i call it from my mvc4 view like @model Fancy.Management.Model.Home.IndexModel. View not recognized it. What is the problem i dont know. 
My View is shown below:

```
@model Fancy.Management.Model.Home.IndexModel
<html>
<head>
    <title>Giriş</title>
</head>
<body>
   @Html.BeginForm(){
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Kullanıcı Adı:</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.UserName)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Şifre:</td>
            <td>@Html.PasswordFor(m=>m.Password)</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td><input type="submit" value="Giriş" /></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

My controller is shown below:

```
namespace Fancy.Web.Management.Controllers
{
#region Using Directives
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
#endregion

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    #region Get
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    } 
    #endregion

}
}
```

And my model is shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Fancy.Management.Model.Home
{
public class IndexModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: we dont know either. please show us your view/viewmodel/controller

Comment: I added my code to question.

Comment: what exactly is the problem ? i see that you can use    <td>@Html.PasswordFor(m=>m.Password)</td, so that looks like you can access the properties of your viewmodel?

Comment: Actually intellisense not recognized him. And they are always red. And visual studio always tell me they are wrong. But i builded. Ant got no exception. Whats wrong with visual studio?

Comment: can you run the website, like actually load it in a browser? it might just be a visual studio thing that goes away after a restart

Comment: Yes i can run website. I restarted visual studio. Now everything is perfect. Strange bug. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You added a ref to the model? Ok, that's not enough in order that your view can see it.

First, open the web.config file located in `Views` folder. Then, add a namespace tag for your model class like the following:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
// ...
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    // ...
    <add namespace="Fancy.Management.Model" />
    // ...
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

and finally change your `@model` in your view like this:

```
@model Home.IndexModel
```

The problem should goes away...

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

use like this

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
   #region Get
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
        IndexModel inModel=new IndexModel();
        return View(inModel);
   } 
   #endregion

 }
}
```