# My model is recognized by my controller, but not my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC project and I added a model to my Model's Folder.

> [ProjectName].web.Models.ProductAndClient

That same folder already has another model called 'UserAccount'

When I go to my controller, I can instantiate and use the model normally; I didn't have any issues accessing or seeing the model from the controller.

However, when I go to my view and try to use the model with Razor, it will only show the

> [ProjectName].web.Models.UserAccount

option. It will not pull up ProductAndClient. I have other classes in the bll that I can access, as well. Is is just this one class that the View will not see.

I already tried the web config solution in this [Stack Overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767339/view-doesnt-recognized-my-view-model). It didn't work. Again, the view can already see the model folder, it just wont see the one file.
I have also tried building, cleaning, and rebuilding the solution. I have tried shutting down and restarting Visual Studio. I have tried shutting down and restarting my computer. I have tried deleting and re-creating the class. And I have tried accessing the class from other views. And I triple checked everything says 'public'. None of them work.

As far as the exact 'error', when I type the

```
@model [projectName].web.Models.ProductAndClient
```

The 'ProductAndClient' part has a red squiggly under it. And it says that it does not exist in the namespace. I have used this syntax on several other pages in this project and other projects, so It must just be some random thing I did to make this not work.

```
namespace [projectName].web.Models
{
    public class ProductAndClient
    {
       public ClientInv Client { get; set; } //used as a model for the UI
       public List<ClientInv> Clients { get; set; } //collected info
       public List<ProductCommon> Products { get; set; } //used to compare description and prices
       public List<SelectListItem> ProductNames { get; set; } //used for drop down
    }
}
```

---

```
    using [projectName].web.Models;

   namespace [projectName].web.Controllers
   {
     public class InvoiceController : Controller
     {
         public ActionResult Index()
         {

           //Variables
           ProductCommon productCommon = new ProductCommon();
           List<string> productNames_String = new List<string>();
           ProductAndClient client = new ProductAndClient();

           //Other code that does stuff goes here

           client.Client = new ClientInv();
           client.ProductNames = productNames;
           client.Products = products;

        return View(client);
    }
```

---

```
@model [projectName].web.Models.ProductAndClient
```

Comment: Try closing and reopening the view file. Sometimes Visual Studio "forgets". Restarting didn't help me if the file was open on startup.

Comment: I was really hoping that that's all it was, but, unfortunately, it still refuses to see the model. Thank you though!!

Answer (score 1):

If closing/opening the file doesn't help, try adding a using.

```cs
@using [projectName].web.Models
@model ProductAndClient
```

Or add your model namespace to your web.config

```
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="[projectName].web.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

Comment: I just tried the first solution and it gave me every model in the project except ProductAndClient. For the web.config solution, I found that solution in another stack overflow question before I posted and it didn't work either. Thank you though! I appreciate it!